# Pausing VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can you pause a code from running and then allow it to continue again.

Comment: Change this to a question and answer it yourself. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks will do so later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ToggleButton in a Userform (which initiates your code and `Modal` = `True`)

You can successfully pause the code. With this you can then work in an additional selection to change the operation or function of the code via an addiotn button.

You will need to use public/global variables.

Comments Welcome.

Userform:

```
Public Sub ToggleButton1_AfterUpdate()


    'Program is Paused / Selected to Pause

    If ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        'Changing the Text of the Toggle button once the program is 
         'selected to Pause
        'If program paused then button will display continue
        ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Caption = "Continue"


        'For Sending to  Loop Code
        ProgramStatus = "0"
        Call LoopCode.PrgStat(ProgramStatus)

    End If



    'Program is running / Selected to run

    If ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
        'Changing the Text of the Toggle button once the program is selected to continue
        'If program running then button will display pause
        ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Caption = "Pause"

        'For Sending to  Loop Code
        ProgramStatus = "1"
        Call LoopCode.PrgStat(ProgramStatus)

    End If


End Sub
```

In your Module

```
Public Status As String

Public Sub PrgStat(ByVal ProgStatus As String)

   Status = ProgStatus

End Sub




Sub SomeSub()

 Do While

   ' Some Loop Code Running




          If Status = "1" Then

          'Toggle Not Pressed           

          End If

          If Status = "0" Then

             'Toggle Button Pressed

             Do While Status = "0"
                'Program will stop here until the togglebutton on the 
                'userform is pressed again which changes Status = 1

                'This is where you can make another selection on the 
                'userform

                 DoEvents

             Loop


          End If

   Loop
 End Sub
```